# Consecutive Statement Must be separated by ";" in swift

Tags: swift

So I'm trying out this basic code to understand the mechanics of changing a Circle's position, and I spent a couple of hours debugging this thing, and it seemed like it was working, no clear bugs in Xcode, but when I tried to compile it, it didn't show me any lines or anything, it just said
"Compiling failed: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'"
Any help would be appreciated.
(btw I apologize for the comments, I am not very well versed in commenting code)

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    // creates a variable with the coordinates for the circle
    @State private var Position = CGPoint(x: 200.0, y: 200.0);
    
    // creates a timer to be called later on with the "movement" function
    @State var timer = Timer
        .publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .position(self.Position)
                    .onReceive(self.timer) {_ in self.movement();
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height);
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func movement() {
        withAnimation{
            self.Position.x += 20;
            self.Position.y += 30;
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView();
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me

Comment: @JoakimDanielson [yes](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah sorry ill do that. 
But for me it still completely bugs out, really weird

Comment: @ThatDude021, you definitely don't need `;` anywhere here

Comment: I guess it should be closed as not reproducible then if OP can’t add some more information

Comment: I mean idk that's why I was so confused, there was no indication of a line and it doesn't seem like I need any semi colons, and yet there's absolutely no information other than that statement

Comment: You'd need to provide a reproduce example. Otherwise, there isn't much we could do here

Comment: @ThatDude021 do you get this error in Playground as well or just the Xcode project itself? Or are you perhaps using a different IDE?

Comment: @bxod Im just using the Xcode project and when I try to run the simulation it gives me the error, it also shows up differently than a syntax error, it's directly on top of where the preview screen should be.

Comment: Share a screenshot?

Comment: Sure how can I do that?